# Disable "reload grid" button in nav

Tags: jqgrid

Does anyone know how to disable the "reload grid" button (a.k.a. the "refresh" button) in the grid navigation?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use `refresh:false` paremeer of the navigator (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator):

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh:false });
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  That seems so simple.  I just didn't try the refresh: false in the nav parameters.  Don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Realized by accident that none of the navigation buttons, including the "Reload Grid" button, appear if you omit the `$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', ...)` call.